# Order by not working in HQL inside Grails Controller

Tags: grails, sql-order-by, hql

I have the following inside my controller

```
def pgtyp = Pgtyp.executeQuery("select p.date_hour,p.visits, p.mv, p.browser,p.pagetype,p.platform,p.device 
           from Pgtyp p 
           where p.pagetype = ? and p.device = ? and p.browser = ? and p.platform = ? order by p.date_hour[params.pagetype,params.device,params.browser,params.platform])
```

The moment I add 'order by p.date_hour', I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: FileWatcher caught serious error, see cause
```

Is there some other way I do an order by date_hour in HQL. How do I make this order by work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.!

```
order by col_0_0_ asc  which is col_[fieldnumber]_0
```

with the first selected field being counted with 0 as fieldnumber